# c++ overload "<<" doesn't work for output "obja + objb"

Tags: c++

I overload "<<" and "+" operators for my class. It works fine if I output single object using `cout<<a;`. But it fails when I output `cout<<a+b;`

**g++ version**: g++ (GCC) 9.2.0

```
class UTF8string{
    private:
        string data;
    public:
        UTF8string();
        UTF8string(string a);
        int bytes();
        int find(string a);
        int length();
        void replace(string a, string b);
        UTF8string operator+(UTF8string &a);
        UTF8string operator*(int a);
        UTF8string operator+=(const UTF8string& rhs){
            data.append(rhs.data);
            return *this;
        }
        friend UTF8string operator!(UTF8string &a);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, UTF8string &a);
        friend UTF8string operator+(int a,  UTF8string &other );
};
```

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, UTF8string &a){
    os << a.data;
    return os;
}
UTF8string UTF8string::operator+(UTF8string &a){
    string b = data ;
    return UTF8string(b.append(a.data));

}
```

my test code:

```
    cout << "test + test2: " << test + test2 << endl; // doesn't work
    cout << "test contains: " << test << endl; // works well
```

**Error**

```
testUTF8string.cpp:38:38: 错误：cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘UTF8string&’ to an rvalue of type ‘UTF8string’  
   38 |     cout << "test + test2: " << test + test2 << endl;  
      |                                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

Comment: Your `operator<<(std::ostream& os, UTF8string &a)` should be `operator<<(std::ostream& os, UTF8string const& a)`.

Comment: Change your `operator<<` to take a `const UTF8string& a` instead. The temporary object produced by `a+b` will not bind to just `UTF8string&`.

Answer (score 3):

You're using references-to-non-`const` throughout.

That is a bad idea.

If you don't need to modify the object through a reference, the reference should be to `const`.

If your reference is not to `const`, temporaries cannot bind to it.

The return-by-value result of your `operator+` is a temporary.

Answer (score 1):

Result of your overloaded `operator+` in `test + test2` is temporary value. Temporary value cannot be passed to function by non-`const` reference.

It can be fixed by using `const` reference:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const UTF8string &a){
    os << a.data;
    return os;
}

UTF8string UTF8string::operator+(const UTF8string &a){
    string b = data ;
    return UTF8string(b.append(a.data));
}
```

It is good practice to always use `const` references when passing arguments which are meant to be read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the solution what @Lightness Races with Monica have suggested you can also overload the `operator <<` for rvalue references like:-

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const UTF8string &&a);
```

It is sometimes useful to overload like this when moving is cheaper then copying.
Or for some reason you want a different implementation in two cases.

**NOTE:** In case of `operator <<` it doesn't make sense to do the oveloading as the data/object being passed to stream should be `const`